# Spectrum of Laplace-Beltrami with piecewise constant coefficients

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, laplacian

By the Laplace-Beltrami with piecewise constant coefficients I means the operator $-div (f\, \nabla .)$ in the 2-sphere. Where $f$ is a piecewise constant function that takes two values $1$ and $a>0$. The spectrum of such operator is known to be discret. Except for the case $a=1$, i can't find any work related to the computation of the eigenvalues and their multiplicity.

Is there any work in this direction?

Comment: I doubt that there is something published, but one never knows. The problem is only apparently simple, since the geometry of the set  $E=\{f=a\}$ enetrs and I believe it is unsolvable in general. Possibly, some assumption on $E$ (it could be an interval with respect to an angular coordinate) could allow to do the computation by separation of variables. Sorry, but I do not know more.

Comment: Yes, in my case of interest E   is interval with respect to an angular coordinate.

Comment: Did you try the case of $S^1$ first (with $E$ being an interval)? Could be a nice warm-up.

Comment: Yes,  the case of $S^1$ (with E being an interval) can be done. we solve the equation in E and $S^1\backslash E$ separably. In these expressions two parameters have  to be found. using the continuity and the continuity of the flux we can find a relation between  a and $\lambda$ ( the eigenvalue). we can show that all the eigenvalues,, except 0, are simple.